# Gerar Token Cartão de Crédito Pagseguro

Tags: c#

Estou utilizando a API do PagSeguro [Git](https://github.com/DesignLiquido/pagseguro-dotnet) e não estou conseguindo achar como gerar o token do cartão de crédito para fazer o checkout transparente.

No projeto de exemplo tem o seguinte comando:

```
// Sets a credit card token.
        checkout.Token = "9a476b3a36124756a343712754638c7c";
```

Na [documentação do PagSeguro](https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/documentacao/pagamento-online/pagamentos/pagamento-transparente) tem que para gerar o token tem que fazer a seguinte requisição via JavaScript

```
PagSeguroDirectPayment.createCardToken({
    cardNumber: NUMERO_DO_CARTAO,
    brand: BANDEIRA,
    cvv: CODIGO_DE_SEGURANCA,
    expirationMonth: MES_DE_EXPIRACAO,
    expirationYear: ANO_DE_EXPIRACAO,
    success: FUNCAO_DE_CALLBACK_PARA_SUCESSO,
    error: FUNCAO_DE_CALLBACK_PARA_FALHA,
    complete: FUNCAO_DE_CALLBACK_PARA_TODAS_AS_CHAMADAS
});
```

Alguém sabe se tem como fazer a geração do Token via API do PagSeguro?

Comment: Segundo a documentação, para fazer isto você precisa usar a biblioteca JavaScript deles. Entretanto acho que pode usar um WebBrowser no seu aplicativo para tentar embutir isto.

Answer (score 1):

O PagSeguroDirectPayment.createCardToken é utilizado para gerar o Token que você precisa para realizar uma transação no Pag Seguro. No seu exemplo, você não criou uma função para callback success. Veja abaixo um exemplo simples para obtê-lo:

```
PagSeguroDirectPayment.createCardToken({
    cardNumber: NUMERO_DO_CARTAO,
    brand: BANDEIRA,
    cvv: CODIGO_DE_SEGURANCA,
    expirationMonth: MES_DE_EXPIRACAO,
    expirationYear: ANO_DE_EXPIRACAO,
    success: function(response){
        var objToken = response;
        var TOKEN = objToken["card"].token;
        //Atribuo o token recebido para uma um campo para finalizar o pagamento (Você poderá chamar um método diretamente também se preferir)
        $("#ALGUM_CAMPO_PARA_RECEBER_O_TOKEN").val(TOKEN);
    },
    error: FUNCAO_DE_CALLBACK_PARA_FALHA,
    complete: FUNCAO_DE_CALLBACK_PARA_TODAS_AS_CHAMADAS
});
```

Depois de atribuir o token a algum campo ou seletor você poderá recuperá-lo para fazer o post ou um ajax lá no Pagseguro para concluir a transação.

Comment: Acho que o AP queria consumir a API em C#.

Comment: Mas a API do PagSeguro para checkout transparente que é o caso é JS... Por C# não vai rolar. Pelo menos ainda não vi nenhuma API deles para consumir com C#...

Comment: O AP mencionou que utiliza uma API em C# disponível no Github. A API que ele menciona foi criada por um membro daqui do SO-pt como um fork da API original do UOL. Então existem pelo menos duas ;)

Comment: Realmente o que eu queria era gerar este código através da API em C#, eu consegui entrar em contato com o cara que criou a API e ele me orientou a fazer via javascript.